# How can I debug a method from a class in Java?

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans, methods

I've created a class called `Rational` that represent a rational number in fraction form (with numerator and denominator). I also created a static method `add` that take two `Rational` and adds them up, with the aid of other private static methods (`gmc`, `lmc`). I'm testing my `Rational` class with a `RationalTest` class (this have the main method). Fractions adding are just not right.

I want to debug my `add` method (using Netbeans debuger), but when I hit debug, it only show variables in the main method, not the variables in my `add` method. I cannot "see" the calculations of my `add` method itself. Is there a way to debug a method that is not in the main method?

Comment: Maybe because you're not in the correct scope yet?

Comment: Put the breakpoints inside the `add ` function

Comment: Introduce the breakpoints in your code and debug

Comment: Thanks, it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the breakpoints inside the `add`  function
                    – Shady Atef